# Dictionary and integer input

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, input, types

Python newbie here.

My task is to create a dictionary with months, then ask for a user to input number. If number is 1-12, return name of the month, if user has entered any other number, return 'Please enter valid number in range 1-12' and if user entered anything else (f.e. "What?") - to return '{input} is not a number!'

So far my first issue is that input is string by default. I decided to change type, but then I have issues when user inputs anything else than integer - I get *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'*
But if I leave type string, I have issues when user inputs <1 or >12..

Here is what I have so far:

```
# 1. Create dictionary
months = {
    1: 'January',
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December'
}

# 2. Create input
answer = input('Please input a number of the month: ')
answer = int(answer)

# 3. Create possible outcomes
if answer == 1:
    print(months[1])
if answer == 2:
    print(months[2])
if answer == 3:
    print(months[3])
if answer == 4:
    print(months[4])
if answer == 5:
    print(months[5])
if answer == 6:
    print(months[6])
if answer == 7:
    print(months[7])
if answer == 8:
    print(months[8])
if answer == 9:
    print(months[9])
if answer == 10:
    print(months[10])
if answer == 11:
    print(months[11])
if answer == 12:
    print(months[12])
if answer < 1 or answer >12:
    print('Please input valid number in range 1-12!')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions here are for asking about a specific problem and getting a specific answer. While you'll get general advice anyways, asking specific questions helps people find this question when they have the same problem.
For example, a better question title would be, "How do I interpret user input as an integer?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
answer = input('Please input a number of the month: ')
if answer.isdecimal() and 1 <= int(answer) <= 12:
  print(months[int(answer)])
```

Comment: You can change the conditions to display proper errors as you need

Comment: Thank you, but this returned all the necessary answers for 1-12, but not for any other integer or string.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user has introduced a valid integer, you can put the string to int conversion inside a try-except block. Also, your Step 3 is way too redundant.

```
months = { ... }

answer = input('Please input a number of the month: ')
try:
    answer = int(answer)
    print(months.get(answer, 'The number must be in range 1-12!'))
except ValueError:
    print('That is no integer!')
```

Also, instead of the try-except, you could check if answer is a valid integer using `answer.isdecimal()` before making the conversion. But it wouldn't be aligned with the "ask forgiveness not permission" philosophy.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

One of the main ideas of dictionaries is to avoid multiple "if" statements.

This is a more refined version of your code:

```
# 1. Create dictionary
months = {
    1: 'January',
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December'
}

# 2. Create input
answer = input('Please input a number of the month: ')
try:
    answer = int(answer)
except ValueError:
    print(f'{answer} is not a number!')

if answer in months:
    print(months[answer])

else:
    print('Please input valid number in range 1-12!')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! The only issue I still had was when entering string, return answer were 2 lines, when I needed one. But I solved it now.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, the benefit was learning through the process. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this works perfectly:

```
try:
    answer = int(answer)
    print(months.get(answer, 'Please enter valid number in range 1-12!'))
except ValueError:
    print(f'{answer} is not a number, please try again!')
```